# How to show that$\|Tf\|_{L^p}\leq\pi\|f\|_{L^p}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For $f\in L^p(0,\infty)$, $1\leq p\leq \infty$, define $Tf(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{1+(x-y)^2}dx$, for $0<y<\infty$. Show that $\|Tf\|_{L^p}\leq\pi\|f\|_{L^p}$.

I can prove it for $p=\infty$. For $p\neq\infty$, I use  the integral version of Minkowski's inequality to get $$\|Tf\|_{L^p}\leq\int_0^\infty|f(x)|\left(\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+(x-y)^2}\right)^p \,dy\right)^{1/p} \, dx$$

Comment: This inequality helps:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $1\le p < \infty.$ Let $k_y(x) = \frac{1}{1 + (y-x)^2}.$ Note that $\|k_y\|_1 < \pi$ for all $y>0.$ Using Jensen, we get

$$|Tf(y)|^p \le \|k_y\|_1^p \left (\frac{1}{\|k_y\|_1}\int_0^\infty\frac{|f(x)|}{1+(y-x)^2}\,dx\right)^p \le \|k_y\|_1^p \frac{1}{\|k_y\|_1}\int_0^\infty\frac{|f(x)|^p}{1+(y-x)^2}\,dx$$ $$ = \|k_y\|_1^{p-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{|f(x)|^p}{1+(y-x)^2}\,dx \le \pi^{p-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{|f(x)|^p}{1+(y-x)^2}\,dx.$$

Integrate the last expression with respect to $y$ and use Fubini to see

$$\int_0^\infty |Tf(y)|^p\,dy =\le \pi^p\|f\|_p^p.$$

Taking $p$th roots gives the desired inequality. The result for $p=\infty$ is straightforward.